# How can I add streets as nodes in a osmnx graph?

Tags: graph, openstreetmap, osmnx

If I understood well, the `osmnx` method `graph_from_address` generates a graph in which a `node` refers to the intersection of two or more streets, whereas `edge` refers to a single street connecting two (or more) intersections.

Following this figure, from reference[1], it seems `osmnx` method `graph_from_address` generates something like Fig 1 (b) (axial graph), rather than a connectivity graph as defined in Fig 1(c) of same reference, where streets are nodes instead of edges.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgnmb.png)

Is there a `osmnx` method to extract streets as nodes, rather than as edges?

[1]  Bin Jiang (2009) Ranking spaces for predicting human movement in an urban
environment, International Journal of Geographical Information Science, 23:7, 823-837, DOI:
10.1080/13658810802022822

PS: I have not found anything equivalent in the doc

Comment: networkx.line_graph will produce the dual graph

Comment: I see. It works: thanks @gboeing! PS: I'll check now how to evaluate the outputs to make sure the line graph contains the correct street connections